# ADF/JSF Configuration Data in App Scoped Managed Bean

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

I'm fairly new to ADF/JSF and I've inherited an application that uses a properties file to store application configuration data (as key = value pairs). I tried something like the following example:

```
public class AppScopeManagedBean {

    private static final String property1;

    public AppScopeManagedBean() { }

    static {
        // Load the properties file and initialize fields
    }

    public static final String getProperty1() {
        return property1;
    }
}
```

The problem is that I need to be able to reference these properties in EL bindings as well and ADF (and I presume JSF as well) does not allow me to do this.

What are some recommendations for storing configuration data in an application scoped managed bean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you are setting your managed bean in application scope, there is no reason to have static properties. You can place the static initializer in bean's constructor.
Just use a normal bean  so you can reference it from EL.

Comment: I would like to be able to access the properties statically from other JavaBeans in the application (some in the Model and some in the Controller). The reason being, the previous developer had created a new instance of the properties file class in each class that needed a few properties, and copied the property values into global variables for each of those classes...I'm hoping to prevent or at least discourage this from happening again.

Comment: Than you need to create a factory method: xxx.getInstance() that returns the bean instance from ServletContext.

Comment: Thanks, Florin. I created such a method to do just that. I'm beginning to see this is as good as it gets when trying to prevent other developers from making mistakes while still allowing the ADF runtime environment/container to do its thing.